# Bad Mic Quality For Webcam With MS Teams

Tags: audio, microphone, webcam, microsoft-teams

### Hardware

1. Logitech C925e webcam at the end of my office desk (since I use the top of my monitor for my monitor lamp) for my PC
2. Mic from my HP Elitebook

### Problem

When I use my webcam/pc setup, calls from Teams to Teams are fine. But when I call from Teams to
a phone, the other person can almost not understand me because of a bad audio quality (echo).

### What I tried

When I place my laptop mic at the same spot my current webcam is located, the audio quality for those calls is just fine.

**What can I do to make the audio quality better with my webcam/pc setup when I call a phone?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you can't.

Your laptop very probably contains an **array microphone**.
A simple explanation…

> An array microphone uses two or more microphones to record audible sound waves in a unique way. It focuses multiple sensor elements in different positions, and uses digital signal processing (DSP) to isolate audio sources. This microphone can essentially pinpoint a speaker while moving around a room and extract that signal from background noise. Virtual polar patterns permit the microphone to process signals as if the microphone were placed at the speaker's location. Device housings can resemble dual or circular arrays, or be embedded in telephones, webcams, and other equipment.

<sup>Source: [EasyTechJunkie: What Is an Array Microphone?](https://www.easytechjunkie.com/what-is-an-array-microphone.htm)</sup>

Your webcam very probably has a single mic, or simple non-DSP stereo pair.

The only real solution is to move it much closer to you, use your laptop mic, or find a webcam with an array mic - these are often marketed as 'video conferencing' webcams & tend to be quite expensive.

Comment: Just one questions: how is it possible that it still sounds good when I use my webcam setup and call from Teams to Teams?

Comment: I've never used Teams, but maybe it has some kind of noise cancellation like Skype does. It's nowhere near as good as an array mic, but it's better than nothing at all.